# How to localize the country that will show when searching address using show-address-lookup on LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, google-map

I have a lightning-input-address element on my LWC and the show-lookup-address is set to true. How would I localize the address/ country that will be shown on the dropdown? Currently the lookup search for the addresses in USA first until you typed in the country but I want the lookup to show the address on my country, ex. Philippines. Is there a way to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: The Place Autocomplete API by Google Maps DOES offer this functionality if you pass in the optional ‘location’ parameter. I don’t see that mentioned in the LWC docs though. If you really care about that feature you might need to go the custom route.